# Can I catch the value by using bourne shell script?

Tags: shell, lua, openwrt

When I type some command in openwrt, the result is like this.

```
Security  Signal(%)     Mode
WPA2      86            on
WPA2      42            on
```

In this result, I want to catch the signal value(86) in first column.
How can i catch the value by using bourne shell script?

Plus, luci.sys.call function is only used in cbi file for making Luci, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Try also

```
HereYourCommand | awk 'NR==2 { print $2 }'
```

The awk program prints the second field (aka column) of the second record (aka line).

Answer (score 1):

The following should do:

```
HereYourCommand | head -2 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Replace `HereYourCommand` with your call to `openwrt`.

---

The explanation:

- `head -2`: pick up just the first two lines.
- `tail -1`: from this two lines, pick up the last line.
- `tr -s ' '`: replace multiple spaces with a single one.
- `cut -d' ' -f2`: pick up the 2nd field from the remaining line.

Comment: What about piping with tail +2, instead all that

Comment: @crook `tail -n +2` picks up two lines from the output, further processing is still needed, isn't it?

Comment: Wait I'll post an answer just check it out. Whether it works or not

Answer (score 1):

```
cat test|tail +2|tr -s '\s\t' ' '|cut -d' ' -f2
```

`tail +2` skips first line, then I am replacing spaces or tabs with single space and cut get second field.
output:

```
4
5
8
```

input:

```
x   y   z
1   4   7
2   5   7
4   8   0
```